# Maven comsuming entire Memory while compiling and results in OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory

The maven build of my java 11 project consuming my entire memory while compiling.
The process peaked at 11g and used about 90% of my CPU (i7) on `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867]`.

I am trying to build a multiple module java project for the first time. I've checked out the master branch and the **build is runnig stable on other machines**. It's a Vaadin 14 Application with spring dependencies. The first 3 modules are compiling correctly and the fourth module compiling for ever/results in OutOfMemoryException.

```
[INFO] -----------------< de.bonprix.tracy:tracy-model-impl >------------------
[INFO] Building Tracy - Model Impl 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT                        [4/19]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.1:revision (get-the-git-infos) @ tracy-model-impl ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ tracy-model-impl ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 16 resources
[INFO] Copying 36 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ tracy-model-impl ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 372 source files to C:\dev\workspace\tracy\tracy-model-impl\target\classes
compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.2, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3689)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayDeque.grow(ArrayDeque.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayDeque.addFirst(ArrayDeque.java:291)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayDeque.push(ArrayDeque.java:580)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:310)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:373)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2760)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:520)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getContainer(JavacFileManager.java:316)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:712)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.list(ClassFinder.java:734)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.scanUserPaths(ClassFinder.java:678)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:551)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:299)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder$$Lambda$74/0x00000008002ffc40.complete(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$PackageSymbol.members(Symbol.java:1131)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.listPackageModules(Symtab.java:832)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:345)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:529)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:286)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:301)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:576)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:560)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1066)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:937)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$$Lambda$67/0x00000008002fa040.call(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am running Maven 3.6.3 shipped with latest IntelliJ:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 
2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\dev\java\jdk-11.0.2
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Maven using this OpenJDK 11:

```
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

The shortend pom.xml of the failing module:

```xml
    
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/i18n</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/generated</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${git-commit-id-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>

                <generateGitPropertiesFile>false</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
                </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                <failOnNoGitDirectory>true</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                <failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>true</failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>
                <runOnlyOnce>false</runOnlyOnce>
                <excludeProperties>
                    <excludeProperty>git.user.*</excludeProperty>
                </excludeProperties>
                <includeOnlyProperties>
                    <!-- <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.full$</includeOnlyProperty> -->
                </includeOnlyProperties>
                <useNativeGit>false</useNativeGit>
                <abbrevLength>7</abbrevLength>
                <commitIdGenerationMode>flat</commitIdGenerationMode>
                <gitDescribe>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <always>true</always>
                    <abbrev>7</abbrev>
                    <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
                    <match>*</match>
                    <tags>false</tags>
                    <forceLongFormat>false</forceLongFormat>
                </gitDescribe>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.bonprix.tracy</groupId>
        <artifactId>tracy-model-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tracy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdgssconfig</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.bonprix.tracy</groupId>
        <artifactId>tracy-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.bonprix.mdp.gcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**What i have tried so far:**

- Start build via command line (not via intellij)

  -> Same result (full memory)
- Building an other project

  -> no problems
- Setting -Xmx4G

  -> Consumes 4G+ an fails with an OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Where is it failing? During the build or while running Tests? Second `fourth module compiling for ever/results in OutOfMemoryException.` where exactly? Why defining `src/main/generated` ? Which version of Spring Boot / Vaadin are you using? etc.

Comment: Hey @khmarbaise!
it's failing while compiling the sources.
> Why defining src/main/generated ?
a colleague defined it years ago, idk the reason.

Spring: 5.1.4.RELEASE
Vaadon: 14.4.9

The failing module does not contain a Vaadin dependency.

Comment: Is there a reason to use an older 11.0.X version instead of most recent one? Second please show the full error output and not only excerpts...

Comment: switching to OpenJDK 16 solved the problem. Thank you @khmarbaise!